# Python Requests get doesn't return unless a timeout is specified

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

This request never returns (or at least not within my patience):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?rcprop=ids&format=json&action=query&rclimit=10&rctype=edit&list=recentchanges&rcnamespace=0', headers={'user-agent': 'api test'})
```

Hitting Ctrl+C always produces this traceback:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 330, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 542, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 367, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
```

Adding `timeout=5` to the request causes the request to succeed, after the timeout has expired (ie the correct data is returned from the API request).  But of course that adds five seconds of latency into my application for every API request.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Do you use python3? I use python2.7.5 OK!

Comment: your request worked fine when I tried it, both python 3.4 and 2.7, could be related to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to IPv6 not working very well on my network.  httplib (and therefore Requests) seems to prefer IPv6 if it's available, but if it's not working very well then you can have a long wait while the IPv6 request times out.  Setting a timeout causes it to fall back to IPv4 following the expiry of the timeout, which then succeeds.  Disabling IPv6 on my network has fixed this (as, I assume, would fixing IPv6).